# Drawing many strings very efficiently in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

In a UIView occupying the entire screen I need to draw some hundred rectangles with text inside.

The UIView reacts to pan and pinch, moving and zooming the rectangles.
The text font changes according to the zooming.

I need a very fast way to draw the strings inside the rectangles. What I found so far is too slow.

I am add a test-example, the drawRect of a UIView, without zooming to be simple. It takes ~0.5 seconds on a iPad2 to draw the rectangles, which is very a long wait.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Prepare the rectangles in which to draw the strings
    // in the real app the size of the rectangles will change according to the zooming
    // this takes very little time
    CGRect rectangles[600] ;
    float width = self.frame.size.width / 20.;
    float height = self.frame.size.height / 30.;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) 
        {
            rectangles[k] = CGRectMake(i * width , j * height, width, height);
            k++;
        }
    }


    // In the real app, the font size will change according to the zooming
    // it cannot be stored once for all
    float txtSize = self.frame.size.width / 30. / 4;

    NSDictionary *attributesTitle = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-bold" size:txtSize],
                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:txtSize],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};


    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage ;

    NSRange glyphRange;

    NSLog(@"Before");
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) 
    {
        // In the real app, the font size will change according to the zooming, then the textStorage is not 

        // first string with title
        textStorage = [ [NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A:%d", i] attributes:attributesTitle];
        [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
        glyphRange  = [layoutManager  glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
        [layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange: glyphRange atPoint: rectangles[i].origin];
        // second string with subtitle
        textStorage = [ [NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"B:%d", i] attributes:attributes];
        [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
        glyphRange = [layoutManager  glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
        [layoutManager drawGlyphsForGlyphRange: glyphRange atPoint: CGPointMake(rectangles[i].origin.x, rectangles[i].origin.y + 10)];
    }
    NSLog(@"After");
}
```

On Android I reached a better performance, but I am not so skilled in Objective-C

Comment: Use Instruments to find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: ideally you would just be scaling a vector instead of re-rendering glyphs.

Comment: @BradAllred Thanks for the suggestion, would you give me some guidance on that ?

Comment: have you tried using CoreAnimation for this instead? `CATextLayer` (and perhaps `CAShapeLayer`) seem like what you are looking for.